# doWork() for WorkManager called multiple times for OneTimeWorkRequest

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-workmanager, countdownlatch

I have just started to explore `WorkManager` in my app. My app will mostly be offline, so all the data is stored locally using room db. As soon as the device gets connected to a network I want to sync local data to server and then get the latest data and sync local db again. This is my `doWork()` method implementation -

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    Worker.Result[] result = {Worker.Result.retry()};
    count = new CountDownLatch(1);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    try {
        new NetworkHelper.NetworkBuilder(context)
                .setRequestMethod(NetworkHelper.NetworkBuilder.RequestMethod.GET)
                .setTag(NetworkHelper.NetworkBuilder.TAG.FETCH)
                .setResponseListener((response, requestMethod, isError) -> {
                    Utils.printError("onResponse " + isError);
                    if (!isError) {
                        clearDataAndInsert(String.valueOf(response));
                    }
                })
                .build().callFetchData();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        count.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Utils.printDebug(e.getMessage());
    }

    Utils.printError(result[0].toString());

    return result[0];
}
```

in `clearDataAndInsert()` I am inserting the data that was fetched from server to local db using room and for this, I built my own callback listeners and checking if all my data is successfully inserted in the db using atmoic integer like this -

```
@Override
public void onTaskComplete() {
    int remaining = task.decrementAndGet();
    if (remaining == 0) {
        Data source = new Data.Builder()
                .putString("workInfo", "completed")
                .build();
        result[0] = Worker.Result.success(source);
        count.countDown();
    }
}
```

This is how I am enqueing the data -

```
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
            .build();

    Data source = new Data.Builder()
            .putString("workType", "OneTime")
            .build();

    OneTimeWorkRequest request = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SyncWorker.class)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .setInputData(source)
            .build();
WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(request);
```

As you can see I am using `CountDownLatch` to wait for my fetch and insert in local db process to finish and then return success result from `doWork()`. But my problem is, my doWork gets called multiple times, I am guessing that's because result is returning as retry? But I cannot figure out why?

Comment: Have you figured it out yet? having same issue.

Comment: use enqueueUniqueWork() instead enqueue()

Comment: @AnandTiwari, nice work